# React-native-calendars agenda - problem with the renderItem function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm currently facing a pretty annoying issue with the react-native-calendars library, when using the Agenda component. This is the component:

```
 <Agenda
    items={agendaItems}
    selected={selectedDate}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    renderEmptyDate={renderEmptyDate}
    ref={agendaRef}
```

The problem occurs when I add a new element to "agendaItems". If I simply push to that array, everything is good, but once I try to sort the array and the order of elements change when a new item is added, then the renderItem function behaves very weird and on the UI I can see duplicates, even though the "agendaItems" has valid and correct data.

Please help.

Comment: Can you try https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/pull/1795#issuecomment-1064028108 ?

Comment: Also this open PR is what issue you are referring https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/pull/1794

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies after getting the latest version of the package, I was able to use the "reservationsKeyExtractor" attribute on my Agenda component and it worked fine. Thank you very much!